# What do different frequencies in astrophysics data file mean?

Tags: astrophysics, frequency

I have a data file, with the first part looking like this.

```
Bytes Format Units   Label  Explanations
  1- 14 A14    ---     Name   Source name (1)
  16- 16 A1     ---     Flag   Source flag (2)
  18- 22 F5.3   ---     z      ? Redshift 
  24- 29 F6.1   mJy     SC     ? C band (4.86 GHz) flux density
  31- 34 F4.1   mJy   e_SC     ? Uncertainty in SC (3)
  36- 41 F6.1   mJy     SX     ? X band (8.46 GHz) flux density
  43- 46 F4.1   mJy   e_SX     ? Uncertainty in SX (3) 
  48- 53 F6.1   mJy     SK     ? K band (22.46 GHz) flux density
  55- 58 F4.1   mJy   e_SK     ? Uncertainty in SK (3) 
  60- 65 F6.1   mJy     SQ     ? Q band (43.34 GHz) flux density
  67- 70 F4.1   mJy   e_SQ     ? Uncertainty in SQ (3)
      72 A1     ---   l_pC     Limit flag on pC 
  74- 78 F5.2   %       pC     ? C band polarization angle  
  80- 82 F3.1   %     e_pC     ? Uncertainty in pC (3)
      84 A1     ---   l_pX     Limit flag on pX
  85- 90 F6.3   %       pX     ? X band polarization angle
  92- 94 F3.1   %     e_pX     ? Uncertainty in pX (3)  
      96 A1     ---   l_pK     Limit flag on pK
  98-102 F5.2   %       pK     ? K band polarization angle 
 104-106 F3.1   %     e_pK     ? Uncertainty in pK (3) 
     108 A1     ---   l_pQ     Limit flag on pQ 
 110-115 F6.2   %       pQ     ? Q band polarization angle 
 117-119 F3.1   %     e_pQ     ? Uncertainty in pQ (3) 
 121-128 A8     ---     Class  Class
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note (1): The bulk of these data were taken in the Summer and early Fall of 
          2008 (see Table1). For the subset of sources with K and Q-band 
          observations in November 2009, these flux densities and polarization 
          percentages are listed just below the 2008 values for the same source.
Note (2): The jet(or lobe) photometry is quoted for J094123-014251, since for 
          this source the northern jet corresponds to the AT20G position 
          (see Figure 1).
    C = Core;
    J = Jet;
    T = Total.
Note (3): The quoted uncertainties are the quadrature sum of the AIPS IMFIT 
          fitting uncertainty (which is typically slightly larger than the rms)
          and our estimated systematic uncertainty. For the flux densities is 
          the flux calibration uncertainty, which is equal to 1% for the C 
          band,  0.7% for the X-band, 0.8% for the K-band, and 1% for the 
          Q-band.  For the polarization percentages we estimate an uncertainty 
          (based on the measured spread in polarization of our calibrator 
          sources) of 8% in the C-band, 6% in the X-band, 10% in the K-band 
          and 8% in the Q-band.
```

As you can see, there are the C, X, K, and Q bands. Why are they at different frequencies? Are they measuring changes in spectral flux density?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because file formats are not a physics question, not even when the file format was invented by physicists to solve a physics problem.

Comment: @CuriousOne its not a file format question. i just don't understand why you would need different frequencies--that is my question. I thought it would be helpful to provide the data file for clarity.

Comment: Fair, but one warning, unless you wrote this file yourself or you have the documentation, second guessing what it means is problematic.

Comment: @CuriousOne I interned under the professor who compiled these data. I have her permission to use it. I understand what it means, but I saw some different explanations for my question when I was doing more in-depth research, so I thought I would ask here to get a definitive answer. Sorry for the confusion! :)

Comment: On the question of topicality of questions about file formats: we have at least one [meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2898) that relates and there have been question [closed](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26182)  and [some](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206322) [that](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15408) [survived](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26264).

Comment: If the bands wouldn't be at different frequencies, they wouldn't be different bands, would they? It seems to me that the file is actually distracting from your *real* question: Why would an astrophysicist measure the flux density at different frequencies? (To which, without more information, one can really only say "to get spectral information". You'll have to be more specific what this data is supposed to describe and how it was taken for there to be a useful answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data is taken at different frequencies because different frequencies contain different information.

The data here covers a factor of 9 in frequency (equivalently wavelength). Compare this to the factor of 2 accessible by human vision. Given two objects that have the same power at one end of the frequency range, they could very well differ at the other end. Given that (1) there is measured polarization, (2) jets and [radio] lobes are mentioned, and (3) this is radio data, it's pretty clear that these are nonthermal sources and so one can't just measure the flux in a single band and apply a blackbody formula to get it in other bands.

It's hard to tell with just the header, but it seems there is no time variability in this one data file. It's just a list of objects, each with a brightness in each of 4 bands.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver.